# Is there a way to toggle "Turn All Categories On" as active by default when asking for HealthKit permissions?

Tags: healthkit

Would like to toggle all categories on by default when asking for HealthKit permissions to make it easier from UX perspective.

Haven't been able to find anything in docs or forums or StackOverflow​. See screenshot for context.

[Screenshot - HealthKit Permissions Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9zZ0.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. Apple wants users to actively consent to sharing sensitive data with apps.